# In Dynamics Ax, In this case Type of field : EDT, Enum, String or an integer?

Tags: axapta, x++

> You need to store the preferred method of correspondence in a table
>   named Dir Person Table.
>       The solution must meet the following requirements:
>
> - The table must have a field that stores the preferred method of    correspondence. The field must have values of Mail, E-mail, or
>     Unknown. The text representing the preferred method of correspondence 
>     values on forms must be localized to the language used by the user.
>     The values in the database must not be localized.

How should you create the field in Dir Person Table ?

1. A. Create an extended data type (EDT) used to store the preferred method of correspondence. The EDT must extend from the string. Use the EDT to create the field in Dir Person Table.
2. B. Create an enum that stores the preferred method of correspondence and has the values of Mail, E-mail, and Unknown. Use this enum to create the field in Dir Person Table.
3. C. Create a string field that stores the preferred method of correspondence.
4. D. Create an integer field that stores the preferred method of correspondence.

> I did choose B, the enum but others say that it's an EDT that extends
>   a string ?? response A...
>       Any explanation .
>       thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You were correct, it is **B**.

> The table must have a field that stores the preferred method of correspondence. The field must have values of Mail, E-mail, or
>   Unknown

This clearly means it can contain 3 options/enumerations.

> The text representing the preferred method of correspondence values on forms must be localized to the language used by the user.

This means it must use a label that can be localized to the relevant language.

> The values in the database must not be localized.

This means the value in the database must not be "mail", "email", or "unknown" because those would be localized, but instead must be 0, 1, 2, which is an enum.

Whoever says the answer is **A** is wrong.